# How do I add a legend to my heatmap in R?

Tags: r, legend, heatmap, colorbrewer

I have a large dataset of the expression of genes.
The rows are the genes.
The columns are SPECIFIC tissues- so it is the gene expression in that tissue

I'm using the following code to make a heatmap:

`heatmap(expression_all_tissues_matrix, scale= "column",col=brewer.pal(9,"Blues"))`

I do not know how to make a legend.
I've tried to make the legend/key seperately but I cannot figure out how to use "Blues" in brewer.pal.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

The use of the **pheatmap** package with its eponymous function allows to get what you are looking for. The following code allows you to have the legend on the same graph.

```
require(pheatmap)
require(RColorBrewer)
pheatmap(as.matrix(expression_all_tissues_matrix),color=brewer.pal(9,"Blues"))
```

You can also play on several arguments to associate rows and columns by clustering, but if you don't want to classify them, just use the arguments *cluster_rows = F* and *cluster_col = F* . Don't forget to normalize the data, it can help you to have a nicer rendering. Use `?pheatmap` for more information.